# Is it possible to query the ORM of a microservice through its API?

Tags: orm, microservices, api-design

Is it possible to query the ORM of a microservice through its API, and use it as the ORM of another microservice?

E.g. Let's say I have the microservice A with its API (let's call it API_A), its DB (DB_A) and its internal Object-Relation Mapper instances (ORM_A) defining the correspondences between the the classes belonging to the microservice into the structure of the relational DB and managing its access.

Now imagine I want to have a microservice B, with different functionalities respect to A, although with the same ORM as A (and so a DB with the same structure of DB_A, although not necessarily with the same data, as the different functionalities may produce different data).

How do I query/copy/mirror ORM_A into the microservice B in a smart way, so that I have no code duplication and when A changes, also ORM_B changes accordingly with no manual intervention?

Is there the option to query ORM_A into B via its API, and recreate it in the microservice B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that code changes inside API_A could yield code changes inside API_B creates a coupling between the services and their data that would suggest they shouldn't be two different services.

If API_B does in fact perform wildly different functions than API_A and only needs a few pieces of data from structures surfaced by API_A, you should consider a couple different options to ensure the relevant data is accessible to API_B from API_A:

1. Surface the data from API_A in an endpoint that is accessible to API_B. This creates an API contract that is easier to enforce and test. This solution is relatively easy to implement, but creates some dependency relationships between the two APIs.
2. Setup an event topic that you can notify whenever API_A writes data that API_B (or other services) might want to consume. By reading these events, API_B can write the relevant data to its own DB in its own format to avoid coupling with A either by data structures or contracts. This solution requires the creation of event queues, but would be the best solution for the performance of API_B.

One thing that I've seen people struggle with when adopting microservices (I struggled with it myself) was the idea that **data duplication is ok**. Try not to get stuck thinking of data as relational across multiple services because that's how you'll naturally create the kind of coupling that you'll want to avoid in microservices. Good luck!